# Add additional argument to callable function for urlretrieve's 3rd parameter

Tags: python, url, download, urllib

I have a function that downloads a file using the following code:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename, Handle_Progress)
```

`Handle_Progress` is the function that calculates the the progress percentage. The standard function receives 3 arguments:

```
Handle_Progress(blocknum, blocksize, totalsize)
```

For the purpose of my program I need to pass a fourth argument **dlg**.

I tried

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename, Handle_Progress(dlg))
```

while making the function header

````
def Handle_Progress(dlg, blocknum, blocksize, totalsize):
``` but I get the following error: 

>TypeError: Handle_Progress() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'blocknum', 'blocksize', and 'totalsize'`

How can I pass a 4th parameter to the `Handle_Progress` function?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lambda

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename, 
    lambda blocknum, blocksize, totalsize: Handle_Progress(dlg, blocknum, blocksize, totalsize)
)
```